# Effectively non-recursiveness of some sets

Tags: lo.logic, computational-complexity, computability-theory

A set $A$ is *completely productive* if there exists a computable function $f$ such that for every $e$, $f(e)\in (A-W_e)\cup (W_e-A)$‎. ‎A set is *effectively non-recursive* if it is r.e‎. ‎and its complement is completely productive (see Odifereddi's *Classical recursion theory*, ‎p.304)‎.

The set $K=\{n:~n\in W_n\}$ ‎and many other natural examples of non-recursive sets are in fact effectively non-recursive‎. ‎A natural example of an r.e set which is not effectively non-recursive is the set $\{n:~K(n)<n\}$‎, ‎where $K(x)=\mu y\,[\varphi_y(0)\!\downarrow=x]$ is a Kolmogorov complexity function‎. ‎

‎**Question**: Is the set $\{\langle m,n\rangle:‎~ ‎K(m)<n\}$‎ effectively non-recursive?‎ (where $\langle -,-\rangle$ is a standard pairing function).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not. Let $A$ be the complement of this set, and suppose that $f$ witnesses that $A$ is completely productive. Let $S$ be an infinite, computable set of indices that we control (via the Recursion Theorem), and let $i \notin S$ be another index that we control.

Define $W_e$ as follows. If $f(e)=\langle m,n \rangle$ for some $n>i$ and $e \in S$, then let $W_e = \emptyset$. Otherwise, if $f(e)=f(e')$ for some $e'<e$ with $e' \in S$, then let $W_e = \emptyset$. If neither of these cases holds, then let $W_e=\{f(e)\}$.

If there is an $e$ such that $f(e)=\langle m,n \rangle$ for some $n>i$, then let $\varphi_i(0)$ be the corresponding $m$ for the least such $e$. Otherwise let $\varphi_i(0)$ be undefined.

Now there are three cases.

Case 1. There is an $e \in S$ such that $f(e)=\langle m,n \rangle$ for some $n>i$. Then for the least such $e$, we have ensured that $f(e) \notin A$ and $f(e) \notin W_e$.

Case 2. Not case 1, and there is an $n$ such that $\{m : \langle m,n \rangle \in f(S)\}$ is infinite. If we choose a large enough $m$ in this set, then $\langle m,n \rangle \in A$. Thus for the least $e \in S$ such that $f(e) =\langle m,n \rangle$, we have $f(e) \in A$ and $f(e) \in W_e$.

Case 3. Neither of the above cases holds. Then there must be $e'<e$ such that $e',e \in S$ and $f(e')=f(e)$, but $f(e'') \neq f(e)$ for all $e''<e'$ with $e'' \in S$. Then $f(e) \in W_{e'}$ but $f(e) \notin W_e$. Thus we get a contradiction whether $f(e) \in A$ or not.

**Edit:** To be more precise about the definition of $S$ and $i$, what we actually do is define a computable binary function $g$ as follows. Given $j$, for each $e>0$ in order, let $g(j,e)$ be a number $k$ such that $k>g(j,e')$ for $0<e'<e$ and $W_k$ acts as follows: Until $\varphi_j(e')$ converges for all $e' \leqslant e$, no number enters $W_k$. If $f(\varphi_j(e)) = \langle m,n \rangle$ for some $n \leqslant \varphi_j(0)$ and $f(\varphi_j(e)) \neq f(\varphi_j(e'))$ for all $e' < e$ then $f(\varphi_j(e))$ enters $W_k$. Otherwise, no number enters $W_k$. Let $g(j,0)$ be an $l$ such that $\varphi_l(0)=m$ for the $m$ corresponding to the least $e>0$ such that $f(\varphi_j(e))=\langle m,n \rangle$ with $n>\varphi_j(0)$ if there is such an $e$, and $\varphi_l(0)$ diverges otherwise. Notice that $g$ is total. By the Second Recursion Theorem, there is a $j$ such that $\varphi_j(e)=g(j,e)$ for all $e$. Let $S=\{g(j,e) : e>0\}$ and let $i=g(j,0)$.

Comment: Obviously, you do not literally "define" $W_e$ (it is what it is), but, as you indicate, you use the RT to somehow produce an $e$ with certain properties. The second half of the argument seems to use a family of $e$'s, so you are probably applying the RT with parameters. Can you make these steps more explicit please?

Comment: @Christian Remling: I've added a paragraph to my answer to make the use of the Recursion Theorem explicit.

Comment: Thanks a lot prof. Denis Hirschfeldt for the brilliant answer. Is there any reference in which this theorem has been proved?

Comment: @Saeed Salehi: I think there's a good chance that this (or something close to it) has been proved somewhere, but I don't know a reference at the moment.

Comment: Maybe also worth mentioning: Odifreddi also establishes (it's easy in fact) that effectively non-recursive is equivalent to $m$-complete, so also equivalent to creative.